# Get next item of a given string item in a List<>

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list of data that I want to iterate through by looking for string value matches, and the list looks like this:

[image]

and I want output as :

[image]

To achieve this i tried using linq but I am not getting desired output.

```
List<WorkItemStateTime> workItems = new List<WorkItemStateTime>();               

int totalCount = 0; int currentId = 1;
string currentState;

totalCount = revisionData.Count;
do
{
    WorkItemStateTime workItemStateTime = new WorkItemStateTime();
    var currRow = revisionData.Where(x => x.rev == currentId).FirstOrDefault();                    
    currentState = currRow.fields.SystemState;
    workItemStateTime.State = currentState;
    workItemStateTime.StartTime = currRow.fields.SystemChangedDate;

    var nextRow = revisionData.SkipWhile(x => x.fields.SystemState != currentState).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
    currentId = nextRow.rev;
    workItemStateTime.EndTime = nextRow.fields.SystemChangedDate;
    workItems.Add(workItemStateTime);

} while ((currentId - 1) < totalCount);
```

Comment: To achieve the desired output where you want to group consecutive rows with the same state and calculate the start and end dates, you can use LINQ in a more organized way.

Comment: @SHUBHAMSHEDGE, I don't think group by will work here.. Because here sequence of states are important.. Look at Row no 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ is really bad if you need interaction between the items of your list. In your case, you need the start time of the next item with a different state. I recommend you use a classical loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i+1; j < data.Count; j++)
            {
                if(data[i].State != data[j].State)
                {
                    result.Add(new Item { State = data[i].State, Start = data[i].Start, End = data[j].Start });
                    i = j;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            result.Add(new Item { State = data[i].State, Start = data[i].Start, End = DateTime.Now });
        }
```

The out loop goes over your complete input. The inner loop goes until it finds an item with a different state. If this item is found, we add a new item to the result list with the start time of the first item and the end time of the item found in the inner loop. Then all these items with the same state are skipped by setting the index of the outer loop to the index of the inner loop. If no item is found, we are obviously at the end of the list an we add an item to the result list with the end time being the current time.

Online-demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jfgvuj

Answer (score 1):

Within the Reactive Extensions exists the method [*DistinctUntilChanged*](https://rxmarbles.com/#distinctUntilChanged). By implementing a similar approach for *IEnumerable* you could achieve the same:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctUntilChangedBy<T, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        Func<T, TKey> keySelector,
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer = null)
    {
        keyComparer ??= EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;

        var last = default(TKey);
        var haveLast = false;

        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            var current = keySelector(item);
            if (!haveLast || !keyComparer.Equals(last, current))
            {
                haveLast = true;
                last = current;
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use this method you can take a look the following example:

```
    var items = new[] 
    {
        new MyItem { Value = 1, Name = "A" },
        new MyItem { Value = 2, Name = "B" },
        new MyItem { Value = 2, Name = "C" },
        new MyItem { Value = 3, Name = "D" },
        new MyItem { Value = 2, Name = "E" },
        new MyItem { Value = 1, Name = "F" },
    };

    var distinctItems = items.DistinctUntilChangedBy(item => item.Value);

    foreach (var item in distinctItems)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.Value} {item.Name}");
    }
```

And the output would be:

```
1 A
2 B
3 D
2 E
1 F
```